# How to use Google Analytics API to show information about specific page in C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have configured the Analytics account and written the program in C# that tells the user current pageviews. I want to find out the number of users for a specific page on my blog. Is this even possible and if it is how can I do it.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: @bjb568 No code is needed to answer this question.  He just wants to know what dimensions and metrics to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all the dimensions and metrics available with the Google analytics API here:[Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

You might want to try and test out your queries here its a little easer:  [Google Analytics Query Explorer 2](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)

To see the number of users per page you could do something like:  Dimension `ga:pagePath` with a dimension of `ga:visits`.